# How to properly add brackets to SQL queries with 'or' and 'and' clauses by using Arel?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to generate the following SQL query:

```
SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (`articles`.`user_id` = 1 OR `articles`.`status` = 'published' OR (`articles`.`status` = 'temp' AND `articles`.`user_id` IN (10, 11, 12, <...>)))
```

By using [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) this way

```
Article
 .where(
   arel_table[:user_id].eq(1)
   .or(arel_table[:status].eq("published"))
   .or(
     arel_table[:status].eq("temp")
     .and(
       arel_table[:user_id].in(10, 11, 12, <...>)
     )
  )
)
```

it generates the following (*note*: brackets are not the same as the first SQL query):

```
SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (((`articles`.`user_id` = 1 OR `articles`.`status` = 'published') OR `articles`.`status` = 'temp' AND `articles`.`user_id` IN (10, 11, 12, <...>)))
```

Since *I think* the latter SQL query doesn't "work" as the first one, **how could I use Arel** (or, maybe, something else) **so to generate the SQL query as the first one?**

#### Update (after comments)

Given SQL queries above "work" the same but I still would like to generate the exact SQL query as the first one in the question (the main reason to make this is that the first SQL query is more readable than the second since in the first one are used less and "explicit" brackets), how could I make that by using Arel?

Comment: You sure these aren't the same?

Comment: @Charleh - No, not at all. Frankly speaking, I can not "manually" test that because there are a lot of records in the database: it is almost impossible to prove that in less than 2 or more hours by "inspecting" each object (... losing your eyesight and becoming crazy)!

Comment: They're equivalent. `AND` binds more tightly than `OR`. You only *have* to apply brackets if you want multiple `OR` conditions on one side or the other of an `AND` condition.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - If, for syntactic correctness purposes, I would like to generate the exact SQL query as the first one in the question, how could I make that?

Comment: If you still don't trust the query, you can easily write this as a test SQL query to test equivalence - e.g. something like: SELECT 1 WHERE ((1 = 1 OR 0 = 1) OR 0 = 1 AND 1 = 1), and just change the values to test different combinations of brackets and true/false values

Comment: @Charleh - I trust the query. I also updated the question.

Comment: I'd update again because technically the syntax is perfectly correct - you will find a lot of SQL generation tools add brackets around the whole of the WHERE clause - not sure why there are 2 sets, but syntactically it's solid, is there a good reason to care about the way the query is written as long as it works?

Comment: @Charleh - My main reason is that the SQL query statement is more **readable** since in the first one are used *less* and *"explicit"* brackets.

Comment: the title should be renamed to "parentheses" instead of "brackets"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully used this gem: [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) which comes on top of Arel so you don't have to mess with it. So in order to generate your query you would do something like this in Squeel:

```
@articles = Article.
  where{
  ( user_id.eq(1) | status.eq('published') ) |
  ( user_id.in([10, 11, 12, '<...>']) & status.eq('temp') )
}

# since this is an ActiveRecord::Relation we can play around with it
@articles = @articles.select{ [ user_id, status ] }

# and you can also inspect your SQL to see what is going to come out
puts @articles.to_sql
```

The more complicated your queries get the more you're going to like this gem.

Comment: I like that gem and I also heard of MetaWhere, but I tend to don't use third-party gems (at least when it is possible and reasonable) because those may be "abandoned" at any time (that is, no more developed) and because the Ruby on Rails framework could change so I have to "wait" that those gems have been updated (that is, I cannot update my application to the last RoR version until third-party gems are updated as well). My reasoning on *no-using* third-party gems might be correct?

Comment: I opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192688/is-it-right-to-tend-to-dont-use-third-party-gem) related to my last comment.

Comment: All these gems: Squeel, MetaWhere & MetaSearch are maintained by the same guy: [Ernie](http://rubygems.org/profiles/ernie). I have the same philosophy as you but slowly I'm trying not to think like this. Chances are somebody already ran into the same issue as you did and has a solution for it. Go for it. It's true that with open source there is the risk for a module being abandoned. But they can always be picked up by somebody else. There is a nice Railcast on [MetaWhere & MetaSearch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch). I think working directly with Arel is pretty messy..

Comment: And as soon as your queries get more complex (joins, conditions etc.) you'll want to switch to something that does the heavy lifting of working with arel. There are a lot of tools out there, try them out and see which one works for you.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. I was searching the web for some hours and finally found a method named [grouping](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/FactoryMethods#grouping-instance_method) in [Arel::FactoryMethods](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/FactoryMethods) which simply adds brackets around an expression.

You should wrap your *groups* with a `arel_table.grouping(...)` call.

Answer (score 8):

Example of how to use `arel_table.grouping(...)` as part of scope

```
# app/model/candy.rb
class Candy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :candy_ownerships
  has_many :clients, through: :candy_ownerships, source: :owner, source_type: 'Client'
  has_many :users,   through: :candy_ownerships, source: :owner, source_type: 'User'

  # ....
  scope :for_user_or_global, ->(user) do
    # ->() is new lambda syntax, lamdba{|user| ....}

    worldwide_candies  = where(type: 'WorldwideCandies').where_values.reduce(:and)
    client_candies     = where(type: 'ClientCandies', candy_ownerships: { owner_id: user.client.id, owner_type: 'Client'}).where_values.reduce(:and)
    user_candies       = where(type: 'UserCandies',   candy_ownerships: { owner_id: user.id,        owner_type: 'User'  }).where_values.reduce(:and)

    joins(:candy_ownerships).where( worldwide_candies.or( arel_table.grouping(client_candies) ).or( arel_table.grouping(user_candies) ) )
  end

  # ....
end
```

call

```
Candy.for_user_or_global(User.last)
#=> SELECT `candies`.* FROM `candies` INNER JOIN `candy_ownerships` ON `candy_ownerships`.`candy_id` = `candies`.`id` WHERE (`candies`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND (((`candies`.`type` = 'WorldwideCandies' OR (`candies`.`type` = 'ClientCandies' AND `candy_ownerships`.`owner_id` = 19 AND `candy_ownerships`.`owner_type` = 'Client')) OR (`candies`.`type` = 'UserCandies' AND `candy_ownerships`.`owner_id` = 121 AND `candy_ownerships`.`owner_type` = 'User')))
```

thx [micha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15162661/473040) for the tip