# How to control bracket position on ActiveRecord query with `OR` clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate the following SQL query using ActiveRecord for Rails:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (((1 IS NULL) OR (10 > 20)) AND (2 IS NULL OR (10 > 1)));
```

So I wrote the following scope:

```
where('1 IS NULL')
  .or(where('10 > 20'))
  .where('2 IS NULL')
  .or(where('10 > 1'))
```

However I am getting a slightly different query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (((1 IS NULL) OR (10 > 20)) AND 2 IS NULL OR (10 > 1));
```

Note that the first has no brackets surrounding everything after `AND` whilst the first does. This effects the results I get (the first query evaluates to false whilst the second true).

How can I write the second query using ActiveRecord?

This question seems very similar: [How to properly add brackets to SQL queries with 'or' and 'and' clauses by using Arel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190792/how-to-properly-add-brackets-to-sql-queries-with-or-and-and-clauses-by-using) Arel is now part of Rails so any answer there should be relevant.

The difference is both queries are the same which lead to a discussion about how to make it clearer, and secondly it was for an older version of Rails so the answers don't seem to work.

I also don't want to need a new gem for this, I think ActiveRecord should be able to handle this.

Edit:

I ended up writing it like this:

```
where("(1 IS NULL OR 10 > 20) AND (2 IS NULL OR 10 > 1)")
```

but now I'm just going around ActiveRecord, I was hoping to do it with ActiveRecord

Comment: I’ve had similar problems with rails where it’s made more sense to drop back to just using SQL. Try wrapping your query in an sql view, then writing a read-only model around the view and querying that. It can simplify away so much complexity, compared to an over-complex AREL statement.

Comment: @AJFaraday I know, I often drop back to SQL but when it's something like this, I really think there must be a way to do it with plain ActiveRecord,a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶m̶e̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶w̶r̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶I̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶?̶   I guess I could just only fill in a single where clause with a couple parameters

Comment: Fair empty, if you have a reason to work this way. I’m sure there is a literal answer to the question. I found a blog with a couple of suggestions for combining scopes, which might help. https://reinteractive.com/posts/358-frankenstein-s-activerecord-how-to-stitch-together-complex-activerecord-queries-from-simple-parts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get something similar, just without the main parentheses wrapping the where clause conditions:

```
User.where('foo IS NULL')
    .or(User.where('10 > 20'))
    .merge(User.where(bar: nil).or(User.where('10 > 1')))
# SELECT "users".*
# FROM "users"
# WHERE ((foo IS NULL) OR (10 > 20)) AND ("users"."bar" IS NULL OR (10 > 1))
```

Consider `foo` equals `1` and `bar` equals `2`.

Comment: Thanks `merge` is exactly what I was looking for! The main parentheses aren't needed as long as they are logically equivalent (which they are)

Comment: I must mention that in this case it would probably be better to use "raw" SQL. The ActiveRecord way is unecessarilly complicated.